# PHP: How to split this array into two separate arrays or values?

Tags: php, arrays

```
{"cae7fc":
["1519106711000 1008.48","1519107011000 1000.28","1519107311000 1009.89","1519107611000 1000","1519107910000 1006.52","1519108211000 985.68","1519108511000 1009.16","1519108812000 1003.5","1519109111000 998.09"]}
```

I would like to be able to pull the two values into two separate values, for example, "1519106711000" & "1008.48", date and rate.

Comment: Explode by space.

Comment: Try using `explode()` by space for each `"cae7fc"` array element

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Explode doesn't work because php throws the "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given" error.

Comment: @albertR yes this is an expected error, because `explode()` returns an array, so you have to access it by index, check my solu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are :

```
$json = json_decode('["1519106711000 1008.48","1519107011000 1000.28","1519107311000 1009.89","1519107611000 1000","1519107910000 1006.52","1519108211000 985.68","1519108511000 1009.16","1519108812000 1003.5","1519109111000 998.09"]');

$data = [];
foreach ($json as $row) {
    $row = explode(' ', $row);
    $data[] = ['date' => $row[0], 'rate' => $row[1]];
}

// you can use $data however you want
// it will give you something like this :
/*
[{"date":"1519106711000","rate":"1008.48"},{"date":"1519107011000","rate":"1000.28"},{"date":"1519107311000","rate":"1009.89"},{"date":"1519107611000","rate":"1000"},{"date":"1519107910000","rate":"1006.52"},{"date":"1519108211000","rate":"985.68"},{"date":"1519108511000","rate":"1009.16"},{"date":"1519108812000","rate":"1003.5"},{"date":"1519109111000","rate":"998.09"}]
*/
```

Comment: Hesham, thank you for all your help. You rock! Unfortunately, the string I've provided has already been run through the json_decode(); The json_decode(); includes the "cae7fc" element.

Comment: @albertR  then instead `$json ` you can use `foreach ($json['cae7fc'] as $row)`

Comment: Team, a combination of the two solutions seems to work. Thank  you for your help and taking the time to help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `regex` with `preg_match_all` to achieve what you are up to,

```
$json='{  
   "cae7fc":[  
      "1519106711000 1008.48",
      "1519107011000 1000.28",
      "1519107311000 1009.89",
      "1519107611000 1000",
      "1519107910000 1006.52",
      "1519108211000 985.68",
      "1519108511000 1009.16",
      "1519108812000 1003.5",
      "1519109111000 998.09"
   ]
}';

preg_match_all('/(?<=")\d+/', $json, $date);
preg_match_all('/[\d\.]+(?=")/', $json, $rate);
```

This will give you `$date` and `$rate` arrays like below

**`$date`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1519106711000
            [1] => 1519107011000
            [2] => 1519107311000
            [3] => 1519107611000
            [4] => 1519107910000
            [5] => 1519108211000
            [6] => 1519108511000
            [7] => 1519108812000
            [8] => 1519109111000
        )

)
```

**`$rate`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1008.48
            [1] => 1000.28
            [2] => 1009.89
            [3] => 1000
            [4] => 1006.52
            [5] => 985.68
            [6] => 1009.16
            [7] => 1003.5
            [8] => 998.09
        )

)
```

Comment: Please explain the code you suggest and how it is supposed to help. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem you may use the functions:

- `explode`
- `sscanf`
- `preg_match`
- `preg_split`

Example using `sscanf`:

```
<?php

$json =
<<<EOF
{"cae7fc":
    ["1519106711000 1008.48","1519107011000 1000.28","1519107311000 1009.89","1519107611000 1000","1519107910000 1006.52","1519108211000 985.68","1519108511000 1009.16","1519108812000 1003.5","1519109111000 998.09"]}
EOF;

$data = array();
foreach((array)json_decode($json, true) as $key => $values) {
    $data[$key] = array();
    foreach ($values as $valuesPairStr) {
        sscanf($valuesPairStr, '%d %f', $date, $rate);
        $data[$key][] = array(
            'date' => $date,
            'rate' => $rate,
        );
    }
}
```

Another example using `explode`, `array_walk` and `array_map`:

```
<?php

$json =
<<<EOF
{"cae7fc":
    ["1519106711000 1008.48","1519107011000 1000.28","1519107311000 1009.89","1519107611000 1000","1519107910000 1006.52","1519108211000 985.68","1519108511000 1009.16","1519108812000 1003.5","1519109111000 998.09"]}
EOF;
$data = (array)json_decode($json, true);
array_walk(
    $data,
    function(&$item, $key) {
        $item = array_map(
            function($pairStr) {
                $parts = explode(' ', $pairStr);
                return array(
                    'date' => isset($parts[0]) ? (int)$parts[0] : null,
                    'rate' => isset($parts[1]) ? (float)$parts[1] : null,
                );
            },
            $item
        );
    }
);
```